# ls -ltr using PHP exec()

Tags: php, exec

as the problem states.. 
when i do

```
exec("ls -ltr  > output.txt 2>&1",$result,$status);
```

its different from the normal output. An extra column gets added. something like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache   apache    211 Jul  1 15:52 withoutsudo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache   apache      0 Jul  1 15:53 withsudo.txt
```

where as when executed from the command prompt its like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache   apache    211 2010-07-01 15:52 withoutsudo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache   apache    274 2010-07-01 15:53 withsudo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache   apache    346 2010-07-01 15:55 sudominusu.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache   apache    414 2010-07-01 15:58 sudominusu.txt
```

See the difference. So in the first output , my usual awk '{print $8}' fails.
I was facing the same problem with cron. But solved it by calling

```
./$HOME/.bashrc
```

in the script. But not happening using php. If somehow i can "tell" php to "exec" from the usual environment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are only interested in the file names and you want to sort with reverse time.
Try this:

ls -tr1  > output.txt 2>&1

You'll get a list with only the file names, so you don't need awk at all.

Another solution is to specify the time format with "--time-style iso". Have a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)

Comment: Hey ur solution works.. i tried with php AND command line.. Both output were same.. it WILL be the same but i had to be sure..

Answer (score 2):

In your login shell, `ls` is probably aliased so that it prints another date. This would be in your .basrc or .bash_profile.

Explicitly pass the `--time-style=` option to `ls` to ensure that it prints the date in the expected format when using PHP.

Comment: Your suggestion is also correct.. but i guess i can mark only 1 correct.. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not an extra output, that's a difference in formatting the date. Apparently you have a different locale set in PHP and in bash ("command prompt").

(in bash, running `export LANG=C` or `export LANG=en_US` gives the result with three-letter month name)

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ls` is heavily dependent on the environment (e.g., `LANG` being the important variable here).  Why not use a combination of [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), [`stat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php), and [`krsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php)?

```
function ls($dir_name) {
  $finfo = array();
  foreach (scandir($dir_name) as $file_name) {
    $s = stat(join('/', array($dir_name,$file_name)));
    $finfo[$file_name] = $s['mtime'];
  }
  krsort($finfo);
  return array_keys($finfo);
}
```

This will be safer and a lot more efficient than shelling out to `ls`.  Not to mention that you get the benefit of being about to customize the sorting and filter the results in ways that are difficult to do inside of an `exec`.

*BTW:*  I am by no means a PHP expert, so the above snippet is likely to be incredibly unsafe and full of errors.

Comment: i m not sure abt the code but yeah thanks for the LANG part. My php runs in an environment where the LANG is "c" and the command line LANG is "en_US.UTF-8" which is why the difference..