# ls output changing when used through exec()

Tags: php, date, format, exec, ls

I'm using the `ls` command via PHP and `exec()` and I get a different output than when I run the same command via the shell. When running `ls` through PHP the year and month of the date get changed into the month name:

Running the command through the shell:

```
$ ls -lh /path/to/file
 -rw-r--r-- 1 sysadmin sysadmin 36M 2011-05-18 13:25 file
```

Running the command via PHP:

```
<?php
exec("ls -lh /path/to/file", $output);
print_r($output);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => -rw-r--r-- 1 sysadmin sysadmin  36M May 18 13:25 file
)
*/
```

**Please note that:**
-the issue doesn't occur when I run the PHP script via the cli (it only occurs when run through apache)
-I checked the source code of the page to make sure that what I was seeing was what I was getting (and I do get the month name instead of the proper date)
-I also run the `ls` command through the shell as the `www-data` user to see if `ls` was giving different output depending on the user (the output is the always the same from the shell, that is I get the date in yyyy-mm-dd instead of the month name)

**Update with answer**

`alias` was giving me this:

```
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

From those aliases I was unable to find a switch that was directly responsible for the time display:

```
-C  list entries by columns
-F  append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
-A  do not list implied . and ..
-a  do not ignore entries starting with .
-l  use a long listing format
```

However using `--time-style=long-iso` in PHP did fix the issue.

Comment: enter "alias" in the shell. Maybe you have an alias for ls there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ls -ltr using PHP exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157092/ls-ltr-using-php-exec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls` has a couple command line options for date display format. check that your command line version isn't aliased to include something like `ls --time-style=locale`. The PHP exec'd version will most likely not have this aliasing present and is using default `ls` settings.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` output depends from current locale settings. When you run it from console on behalf yourself it uses your locale settings, but user `www-data` has own locale settings (which probably differ from your). So, I suggest to you specify locale settings explicitly:

```
exec("LC_TIME=POSIX ls -lh /", $output);
```

where instead of `POSIX` you may substitute locale which you want to use.